# Where to define typecast to struct in MATLAB OOP?

Tags: matlab, oop, casting

In the MATLAB OOP framework, it can be useful to cast an object to a struct, i.e., define a function that takes an object and returns a struct with equivalent fields.

What is the appropriate place to do this? I can think of several options:

- Build a separate converter object that takes care of conversions between various classes
- Add a function `struct` to the class that does the conversion to struct, and make the constructor accept structs

Neither option seems to be very elegant: the first means that logic about the class itself is moved to another class. On the other hand, in the second case, it provokes users to use the `struct` function for *any* object, which will in general give a warning (`structOnObject`).

Are there altenatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd go with the second option, and not worry about provoking users to call `struct` on other classes; you can only worry about your own code, not that of a third-party, even if the third party is MathWorks. In any case, if they do start to call `struct` on an arbitrary class, it's only a warning; nothing actually dangerous is likely to happen, it's just not a good practice.

But if you're concerned about that, you can always call your converter method `toStruct` rather than `struct`. Or perhaps the best (although slightly more complex) way might be to overload `cast` for your class, accepting and handling the option `'struct'`, and passing any other option through to `builtin('cast',...`.

PS The title of your question refers to *typecasting*, but what your after here is *casting*. In MATLAB, typecasting is a different operation, involving taking the exact bits of one type and reinterpreting them as bits of another type (possibly an array of the output type). See `doc cast` and `doc typecast` for more information on the distinction.

Answer (score 0):

The second option sounds much better to me.

A quick and dirty way to get rid of the warning would be disabling it by calling

```
warning('off', 'MATLAB:structOnObject')
```

at the start of your program.

The solutions provided in Sam Roberts' answer are however much cleaner. I personally would go for the `toStruct()` method.